# How to put a list item in bottomnavigation using flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I hope the my title is enough to understand my problem, **How to put a list item in bottomnavigation using flutter?** if not please refer in the picture below and code i provided.

```
return Scaffold(
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
    currentIndex: _currentIndex,
    backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
    selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
    unselectedItemColor: colorScheme.onSurface.withOpacity(.40),
    selectedLabelStyle: textTheme.caption,
    unselectedLabelStyle: textTheme.caption,
    onTap: (value) {
      // Respond to item press.
      setState(() => _currentIndex = value);
    },
    items: [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        title: Text('Clothes'),
        icon: Icon(Icons.design_services_rounded),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        title: Text('Colors'),
        icon: Icon(Icons.colorize_rounded),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        title: Text('Ideas'),
        icon: Icon(Icons.lightbulb_outline_rounded),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        title: Text('Profile'),
        icon: Icon(Icons.face_rounded),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}
}

if i clicked the Clothes , this will happen.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit 1:**

How this is done is as follows:

```dart
// Keep this outside your Widget as it is a constant.
final List<Widget> _widgets = <Widget>[
  ClothesPage(),
  ColorsPage(),
  IdeasPage(),
  ProfilePage(),
];

return Scaffold(
  // This body is new.
  body: _widgets[_currentIndex],
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
    currentIndex: _currentIndex,
    backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
    selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
    unselectedItemColor: colorScheme.onSurface.withOpacity(.40),
    selectedLabelStyle: textTheme.caption,
    unselectedLabelStyle: textTheme.caption,
    onTap: (value) {
          _currentIndex = value;
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            barrierDismissible: true,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  _widgets[_currentIndex],
                  SizedBox(
                    // Use whatever height you desire.
                    height: 90,
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          );
        },
    items: [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        title: Text('Clothes'),
        icon: Icon(Icons.design_services_rounded),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        title: Text('Colors'),
        icon: Icon(Icons.colorize_rounded),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        title: Text('Ideas'),
        icon: Icon(Icons.lightbulb_outline_rounded),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        title: Text('Profile'),
        icon: Icon(Icons.face_rounded),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);


// I have put a card here, you can put any other Widget for the same.
// Do the same for others.
class ProfilePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Text(
          "Profile",
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now, I hope this is what you expect to do via the Bottom Navigation Bar.

Comment: i upvote your post, how do i make it like in the picture?

Comment: Ok. So, my question is what is the point of the `BottomNavigationBar`? Is it so that you can navigate between different screens or show some temporary Widget above your background screen(the white background that you are currently displaying)?

Comment: yes, exaclty Widget above your background screen(the white background that you are currently displaying)?

Comment: Updated, please check.

Comment: Column's children must not contain any null values, but a null value was found at index 0

Comment: Well, I haven't posted the complete code. You need to create proper Widgets for each of them, like I created for `ProfilePage`. You can use different Widgets over there.